# Error in SQL "The multi-part identifier "ExternalKeywords.ID" could not be bound."

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN ExternalKeywords 
ON ExternalKeywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN ExternalKeywords 
ON ExternalKeywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN Keywords 
ON Keywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Comment: but the second one gets different results

Comment: @Ahmad Farid: From your question it was clear it was just a matter of typo, but it was not possible to say which way without knowing your data model. So I offered two possible options I could come up with based on the amount of information you provided.

Comment: yes man, that was a mistake due to copy paste. thanks, i modified it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN ExternalKeywords 
ON ExternalKeywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN Keywords 
ON Keywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Comment: but the second one gets different results

Comment: The second one gets different results because your question was unclear on whether Keywords or ExternalKeywords was the real name of the table--we gave two versions, one of which would work if it was Keywords, and one that would work if it was ExternalKeywords.  By necessity, one of the two had to be wrong!  ;)

Comment: yes man, that was a mistake due to copy paste. thanks, i modified it now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ExternalQuestionKeyword INNER JOIN Keywords ON Keywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  WHERE QuestionID = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the table/alias for `ExternalKeywords`? There isn't one in the code and that's where the error is coming from, as you are attempting a join on the `id` field of `ExternalKeywords`

Looks like it should be

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ExternalQuestionKeyword 
INNER JOIN 
    Keywords 
    ON 
        Keywords.ID=ExternalQuestionKeyword.KeywordID  
WHERE 
    QuestionID = 17
```